# convert locale timezone date time to LAS VEGAS timezone date time

Tags: objective-c, date, datetime

i am trying to convert local date time to Las Vegas date time with timezone  format.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterdatabase = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

dateFormatterdatabase=[[NSLocale alloc]    initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatterdatabase setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yy hh:mm a"];

NSDate *StarEvent = [[NSDate alloc] init];

StarEvent = [dateFormatterdatabase dateFromString:@"15-05-15 12:00 AM"];
```

how can i convert local time zone date time format to LAS VEGAS TIMEZONE FORMAT datetime. ??

for example current time in here is 2015-05-26 11:21:00 IST to LAS VEGAS FORMAT as 2015-05-26 22:52:36 PDT..

how?

Comment: how to convert local date time/timezone to LAS VEGAS DATE/TIME TimeZONE ?

Comment: anyone with the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// *** Set your Destination TimeZone, for Las Vegas its 'PDT/PST, change TimeZone accordingly for other conversions ***'
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"PST"];
// *** Its your current system(device) time zone ***
NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

// *** Set your date to convert ***
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

// *** Calc time difference ***
NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:currentDate];
NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:currentDate];
NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

// *** set current real date ***
NSDate* date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:currentDate];

// *** Set Date Formater ***
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setTimeZone:destinationTimeZone];
[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
NSLog(@"Converted Date %@",[df stringFromDate:date]);
```